# Creating nested subdict python

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, pymongo, key-value

I have some student names of different types and scores of each type in a list.
Eg:

```
students_exam_names = [exam_name1, exam_name2, exam_name3]
students_exam_score = [exam_score1, exam_score2, exam_score3]
students_quiz_names = [quiz_name1, quiz_name2]
students_quiz_score = [quiz_score1, quiz_score2]
students_homework_names = [homework_name1, homework_name2, homework_name3, homework_name4]
students_homework_score = [homework_score1, homework_score2, homework_score3, homework_score4]
```

Similarly for all three as shown below.

I want to have the details in the form of nested dict as follows:

```
details = {'students_exam':{
    'exam_name1':exam_score1,
    'exam_name2':exam_score2,
    'exam_name3':exam_score3
},
'students_quiz':{
    'quiz_name1': quiz_score1,
    'quiz_name2': quiz_score2
},
'students_homework':{
    'homework_name1': homework_score1,
    'homework_name2': homework_score2,
    'homework_name3': homework_score3,
    'homework_name4': homework_score4,
}
```

The length of each students type is different. I tried to get it in the form of list of dictionaries as below but couldn't go further.

```
students_exam = {}

for i in range(len(students_exam_names)):
  students_exam[students_exam_names[i]] = students_exam_score[i]
```

Comment: each dictionary have name and score only how they are different? how each dict has different number of keys, what is the logic here?

Comment: @deadshot Yes each dictionary have only name and score, I mentioned that each sub dictionary is of different length. Eg: 'students_exam' has 3 keys and value, 'students_quiz' has 2 keys and value.

Comment: Please update your question with all the variable names involved. You currently show: `students_exam_names` and `students_exam_score`. Are there others to do with the `quiz` and the `homework`?

Comment: @quamrana Yes correct. I will update the variable names

Comment: Hey i assumed your inputs so you can view my solutions in the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not forget to use `'` when you are defining your inputs:

```
students_exam_names = ['exam_name1', 'exam_name2', 'exam_name3']
students_exam_score = ['exam_score1', 'exam_score2', 'exam_score3']
students_quiz_names = ['quiz_name1', 'quiz_name2']
students_quiz_score = ['quiz_score1', 'quiz_score2']
students_homework_names = ['homework_name1', 'homework_name2', 'homework_name3', 'homework_name4']
students_homework_score = ['homework_score1', 'homework_score2', 'homework_score3', 'homework_score4']
```

Then, simply use the zip function:

```
details = {'students_exam': dict(zip(students_exam_names, students_exam_score)),
           'students_quiz': dict(zip(students_quiz_names, students_quiz_score)),
           'students_homework': dict(zip(students_homework_names, students_homework_score))}
```

The output is:

```
{'students_exam': {'exam_name1': 'exam_score1', 'exam_name2': 'exam_score2', 'exam_name3': 'exam_score3'}, 'students_quiz': {'quiz_name1': 'quiz_score1', 'quiz_name2': 'quiz_score2'}, 'students_homework': {'homework_name1': 'homework_score1', 'homework_name2': 'homework_score2', 'homework_name3': 'homework_score3', 'homework_name4': 'homework_score4'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what if i assume your complete set of inputs are like

```
students_exam_names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
students_exam_score = ['score1', 'score2', 'score3']
students_quiz_names = ['name1', 'name2']
students_quiz_score = ['score1', 'score2']
students_homework_names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']
students_homework_score = ['score1', 'score2', 'score3', 'score4']
```

if so then the following code should do the job.

```
details={}
details['students_exam']={sexam: students_exam_score[students_exam_names.index(sexam)] for sexam in students_exam_names}
details['students_quiz']={squiz: students_quiz_score[students_quiz_names.index(squiz)] for squiz in students_quiz_names}
details['students_homework']={shome: students_homework_score[students_homework_names.index(shome)] for shome in students_homework_names}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need some functions to do these updates:

```py
def update_exam(details, names, scores):
    results = {}
    for name,score in zip(names,scores):
        results[name]=score
    details['students_exam'] = results

def update_quiz(details, names, scores):
    results = {}
    for name,score in zip(names,scores):
        results[name]=score
    details['students_quiz'] = results

def update_homework(details, names, scores):
    results = {}
    for name,score in zip(names,scores):
        results[name]=score
    details['students_homework'] = results

details = {}
update_exam(details, students_exam_names, students_exam_score)
update_quiz(details, students_quiz_names, students_quiz_score)
update_homework(details, students_homework_names, students_homework_score)
```

But since the above functions only really differ in the text name of the key, they can be collapsed further:

```py
def update(details, key, names, scores):
    results = {}
    for name,score in zip(names,scores):
        results[name]=score
    details[key] = results

details = {}

update(details,'students_exam', students_exam_names, students_exam_score)
update(details,'students_quiz', students_quiz_names, students_quiz_score)
update(details,'students_homework', students_homework_names, students_homework_score)
```

And then the loop can become a dictionary comprehension:

```py
def update(details, key, names, scores):
    details[key] = {name:score for (name,score) in zip(names,scores)}
```